# Do Hero Crates respawn?

Tags: star-wars-assault-team

In Star Wars Assault Team, I've bought a few of the hero crates, and it looks like the "upper" crates are still just as expensive but what you get has gotten worse!

Do these crates respawn after a period of time?

For example, I bought the "Gold" crate for 20 gems and got a tier 3 (it had a chance for a tier 4). Now the same crate is a tier 2, with a high chance of tier 3. I also bought the 2500 credit crate (don't remember the name) and now it isn't there at all anymore! My platinum crate is also now down to "Tier 3, with a chance of Tier 4" instead of "Tier 4 with a chance of Tier 5".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the respawning crates, but they did change them. Some days ago they were as you explained: The Gold crate for 20 gems is explained as "Tier 3 or more" (or something like that). For sure they have gotten worse, as before the change I bought a Gold crate for 20 gems, but I got lucky as I got R2D2 Tier4 - so Tier 3 or higher was true at the time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: And why do you think this doesn't give an answer - they just changed the crates and that's it. The game has been launched too early to confirm any pattern in the crates` prices, so for now I think that just accepting the fact will do. If you have something else in mind - please feel free to express it here. I will remove the answer from here myself if you can justify the deletion. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem with he answer is likely that you spend more time talking about what you are doing in game (eg leveling Zucuss for fun) which is totally irrelevant. Basically the first sentence is your answer, the rest is nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Chris - If you find something wrong with the rest of my "answer" I will remove that. What we discuss here is whether or not the whole "answer" could be considered as such (without the quotes) or not.

Comment: @g00dy: I don't have much problem personally. I'm just trying to interpret what the others may be complaining about. I do think it would be neater if trimmed down though but don't take me as any kind of authority. :)

Comment: @Chris - Thanks :) I edited it a bit, without the long part.

Comment: Having played for a few weeks with no change, I'm pretty sure this is the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @g00dy: looks much neater now. Good stuff. :)